# Columns' width get smaller after every updating action of grid with auto width in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs

My extjs version is 4.1.2. I have set all columns' width to "auto" and check out the behaviour both in Chrome and Firefox. It looks normal in chrome, every column doesn't resize after updating, whereas in firefox it gets smaller and smaller. Is there any way to fix such behaviour and stop decreasing of width?
Chrome version: 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit)
Firefox version: 38.0

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve.. Width property of a column should be an integer value instead of 'auto'. By default all columns will be wide as their content, If you want to make flexible width columns you might want to look into flex property and how that works. Either way best of luck